# This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:windows job:artifacts config contains unknown keys: rules

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

That is my current GitLab CI, which works without an error:

```yaml
stages:
  - build


windows job:
  image: …
  stage: build

  tags:
    - "Windows"

  script:
    - …

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./Debug/*.exe
      - ./Debug/*.pdb
```

And I tried to add a rule that artifacts only runs if the branch is “release”:

```yaml
…
  artifacts:
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "release"'
    paths:
      - ./Debug/*.exe
      - ./Debug/*.pdb
```

But GitLab said:

> This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:windows job:artifacts config contains unknown keys: rules.

Answer (score 1):

[`artifacts`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts) does not have an `artifacts:rules` keyword.

[`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) is at the "`job`" level or [`trigger`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger), or [`workflow`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow)

A workaround would be to duplicate the job:

- one job executed when the branch is *not* `release`, with an artifact section
- one job executed when the branch *is* `release`, *without* any artifacts section.